# Using Play 2.0 to create a web service

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I found an old question ["How to use the Play framework to develop a web service"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4512836/how-to-use-play-framework-to-develop-webservice)

I'm trying to use Play 2.0 and Scala to do the same. Will everything still be the same on Play 2.0 with the exception of moving from Groovy templates to Scala templates?

A new example will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots and lots of changes in Play 2.0.  The internal core API is in Scala, with the Java code being a wrapper.

There are three examples in the Play Framework code:

https://github.com/playframework/Play20/tree/master/samples

This may help you see what has changed between versions.