# java framework that will not replace javascript

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, spring, wicket

I am planning to write a medium scale web application. The server side technologies will include **Java**, **Hibernate**, **MySQL** and the client technologies will include **Html**, **CSS**, **Javascript** and **Jquery**.

I am looking for the best suitable Java framework for developing web (Struts, Spring, Wicket and so on).

I consider myself heavy Jquery user and I really prefer to do client side stuff.

**Wicket** for example has modules like the `date picker` and other modules (`AJAX`) that should make life easIer with javascript and acts like a replacement to it. But I really prefer javascript.

I thought of writing an application with client side and Java Web Services.

- What do you think?
- Do you know a framework that isn't **afraid** of Javascript or don't
  suggest replacement to it but tools to use it?

Comment: No framework is "afraid" of Javascript, Wicket isn't either. They just believe (and I fully agree with them) that hand-crafting  Javascript for run-of-the-mill stuff is just an unnecessary distraction, a major source of errors and a waste of money.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Component-based frameworks generally provide ready-to-use components, that come with their own JavaScript code. If you don't like this, I would stick with action-based MVC frameworks, which generally don't care about what you use at client-side.

My preferences go to Stripes and Spring MVC, but YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend the [Play! Framework](http://www.playframework.org/).

It is a MVC based framework and you can use hibernate, work with a MySQL database and it offers templating for easy HTML generation as well as working well with CSS and Javascript (even includes latest JQuery in download). There are also tons of [modules](http://www.playframework.org/modules) you can add to your project to make development faster and easier.

[Play 2.0](http://www.playframework.org/2.0) should be released fairly soon (currently available in beta) which provides support for CoffeeScript and Less CSS [(see here)](http://www.mrspeaker.net/2011/11/14/coffeescript-less-with-play-2-0/) amongst many other new features.

**Edit**

StackOverflow answer showing how easy it is to create webservices in Play: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4513047/681807

Answer (score 0):

Well all the framework you have mentioned (struts, spring, wicket) , none of them afraid of javascript.
Like in Struts2 and Spring they have provided build in ajax support for developer like me who is more comfortable with serverside development than client side work (ajax/jquery fancy stuff).

Its on individual how he/she is using JS with any existing framework and you are even free to use simple HTML at you client side with whatever JS way you want to apply to your UI.

Framework support to UI is always intended to provide a close integration to the server-side so as to speedup the overall development time.

In Short i can not recommend any framework as that will dependent upon you project requirements which fits perfectly as per your need, but none of the framework will stop you to use JS in the way you want to use.