# I am looking for java web framework

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, frameworks, web

I don't know if I should continue the [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8925090/java-framework-that-will-not-replace-javascript) of mine because this is a different question. But the questions are related.

I am looking for web java framework that:
1. will be MVC framework.
2. will be well documented.
3. will allow me use javascript of my own without using the framework modules.
4. will support feature like masterpage in asp.net.
5. will have the ability to create predefined components and use them wherever I need.

Is there something like this?
I appriciate very much examples for those features.

Comment: Java IS NOT JavaScript.

Comment: @Cole"Cole9"Johnson: I considered myself lucky that you told me this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging by the tags you chose, it all points to:

[Spring Web MVC framework](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html)

In my opinion it also satisfies your 5 requirements.

I would recommend using [Spring Roo](http://www.springsource.org/spring-roo) to generate your first project. Roo projects use the technologies that Ralph recommends:

- JSPX, with some preconfigured tagx files
- [Tiles](http://tiles.apache.org/) as templating framework

Roo will also setup Hibernate with Mysql, which are the technologies you mentioned in your other post

Comment: (+1) using Roo at least a demo to have a look how that technology stack works is a good idea -- compleatly independend of the point if you want to use Roo or not

Comment: Agreed Ralph. Even if you don't use Roo, the generated project is still a good reference point. It demonstrates Spring's chosen technology stack and their preferred configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak to #4, because I don't know masterpage, but Spring MVC satisfies the other four requirements.  I'd recommend it highly.

Be warned that Spring has an MVC framework, but it's much, much more.  It's a three-legged stool:

1. Dependency injection and IoC
2. Aspect oriented programming AOP
3. Modules like MVC, persistence with JDBC and ORM, messaging, remoting, security, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend this setup:

- Spring (Spring Core and Spring MVC),
- [Tiles](http://tiles.apache.org/),
- JSPX (*the X markes the spot*)

Tiles for "support feature like masterpage in asp.net."

JSPX, because you can easyly write Tagx files to define your predefined components.