# Play Framework webservice tutorial scala

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I'm pretty new to Play! and scala and i'm searching desperatly for a good step by step tutorial on how to implement a webservice. the documentation is pretty poor and i can't find something that helps.

ps: i have already done the exemple given in the playframework web site it helped a lot for the understanding of the framework but my knowledge to scala is the big obstacle here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4512836/how-to-use-play-framework-to-develop-webservice

Comment: @Edmondo1984 The question you cited is about Play 1.

Comment: true but the idea is the same...

Comment: @Edmondo1984 thank you for your comment but what i wanted is an exemple with the scala language.

Comment: The only thing which needs to be written in Scala is the controller

Comment: I found this tutorial which is really helpfull [Here](http://www.jamesward.com/2012/02/21/play-framework-2-with-scala-anorm-json-coffeescript-jquery-heroku)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well i think this is what i wanted. First lets assume that we want a RESTfull webservice that returns informations about a user. we create the user class as following

```
case class User() {
  val id= 1
  val name = "john"
  val score = 8.5
}
```

then we make the controller which is as follow

```
object Application extends Controller {

  def sum() = Action {
    val user = new User
    val json = Json.generate(user)
    Ok(json).as("application/json")
  }
}
```

and don't forget to add the import for Json which is `import com.codahale.jerkson.Json`

For the route add the following line to your `route` file:

```
GET     /sum                 controllers.Application.sum
```

the result should look something like

```
{
 "id":1,
 "name":"john",
 "score":8.5
}
```